# Wordpress combine query and output different styling dependant on post type

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

I have two WordPress post types the normal 'post' and a custom post type called 'notes'. I want to combine both and sort them by date. I managed to find the combine query and that's working fine. The problem is I'd like to have  different styling for notes. I thought I could do a wordpress if_singlular('notes') to try and target it.. but I'm guessing it's getting lost when the merge happens.

Does anyone know how I could achieve this functionality?

Many thanks!

My php:

```
    <?php
    // An example of creating two separate WP queries, combining the results, 
    // sorting by date and formatting the results for us in a loop like a regular query.
    // order the posts by date in descending order (should go in functions.php to keep things tidy)
    function order_by_date( $a, $b )
    {
        return strcmp( $b->post_date, $a->post_date );
    }
    // get the posts for the first query
    $q1_args = array(
        'post_type' => 'post', 
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'post_status' => 'publish' 
    );
    $q1_posts = get_posts( $q1_args );
    // get the posts for the second query
    $q2_args = array(
        'post_type' => 'notes',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'post_status' => 'publish'
    );
    $q2_posts= get_posts( $q2_args );
    // Merge the post arrays together, and sort by date using the order_by_date function
    $final_posts = array_merge( $q1_posts, $q2_posts );
    usort( $final_posts, 'order_by_date' );
    // Loop over the posts and use setup_postdata to format for template tag usage
    foreach ( $final_posts as $key => $post ) {
        setup_postdata( $post ); 
        // Now we can use template tags as if this was in a normal WP loop
        foreach ( $final_posts as $key => $post ) {
    setup_postdata( $post ); 
    // Now we can use template tags as if this was in a normal WP loop
    echo '
    <article class="item shortNote">
        <div class="snMeta clearfix">
                <img src="'.get_bloginfo('template_url').'/assets/images/sn-icon.png" alt="Short Note" />
                <span class="metaDate">'. get_the_date('M / d / Y').'</span>
                <strong>Short Note</strong>
        </div>
        <h2><a href="'. esc_attr( esc_url( get_the_permalink() ) ) .'">'.get_the_title().'</a></h2>               
    </article>';
}

    }
    ?>
```

Comment: I think that `is_singular('post_type')`, only check if the page you're on is `single-post_type.php`, so you won't be able to target it like that. I'd check the `$final_posts` array that you're looping through, and separate by that. Post type should be somewhere in the objects that `get_posts()` returns, so use that to style them.

Comment: Thanks for the reply dingo.. do you have any examples I could look at to try and piece it together? I'm still learning PHP.. so I'm not entirely sure where I'd start with that approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so this should do it:

```
<?php
    // An example of creating two separate WP queries, combining the results,
    // sorting by date and formatting the results for us in a loop like a regular query.
    // order the posts by date in descending order (should go in functions.php to keep things tidy)
    function order_by_date( $a, $b ) {
        return strcmp( $b->post_date, $a->post_date );
    }
    // get the posts for the first query
    $q1_args = array(
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'post_status' => 'publish'
    );
    $q1_posts = get_posts( $q1_args );
    // get the posts for the second query
    $q2_args = array(
        'post_type' => 'notes',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'post_status' => 'publish'
    );
    $q2_posts= get_posts( $q2_args );
    // Merge the post arrays together, and sort by date using the order_by_date function
    $final_posts = array_merge( $q1_posts, $q2_posts );
    usort( $final_posts, 'order_by_date' );
    // Loop over the posts and use setup_postdata to format for template tag usage
    foreach ( $final_posts as $key => $post ) {
        $post_type = $post->post_type;
        setup_postdata( $post );
        // Now we can use template tags as if this was in a normal WP loop
        <article class="item shortNote ' . $post_type . '">
            <div class="snMeta clearfix">
                    <img src="'.get_bloginfo('template_url').'/assets/images/sn-icon.png" alt="Short Note" />
                    <span class="metaDate">'. get_the_date('M / d / Y').'</span>
                    <strong>Short Note</strong>
            </div>
            <h2><a href="'. esc_attr( esc_url( get_the_permalink() ) ) .'">'.get_the_title().'</a></h2>
        </article>';    
    }
?>
```

I just had to test it on my server to see if it works. So I added the `$post_type` variable that should return the post type, and then I just put that in your class in the `<article>` tag, so you can differentiate :)

*Tip*:

When in doubt what your loop outputs, always do `print_r()`. This will show you what you are dealing with (arrays, strings, objects) so you easily know what to target :)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Amazing! Thank you so much :-) It works.. although theres a double foreach loop which was outputting things twice.. I removed the second and it worked perfectly. Thanks for the tip too!  :-)

Comment: Yeah, totally missed it :D I edited it out :) Happy to help :)